# Let $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ any set. Show that $m^*(A \cup E) + m^*(A \cap E) =m^*(A) + m^*(E).$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ any set. Show that $$m^*(A \cup E) + m^*(A \cap E) =m^*(A) + m^*(E).$$

So since $E$ is measurable we can use $A$ as the set for Carathéodory's extension theorem? We get that $$m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$$ from where we get that $$m^*(A \cap E)= m^*(A) - m^*(A \setminus E).$$

Now we need to determine if $$m^*(A \cup E) = m^*(E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$$ in order to complete the proof.

We can write $A =(A \cap E) \cup (A \setminus E)$ and so $A \cup E =( (A\cup E) \cap E) \cup ((A \cup E) \setminus E))). $ Now $$m^*(A \cup E) =m^*(( (A\cup E) \cap E) \cup ((A \cup E) \setminus E)))) = m^*(E)+ m^*(A \setminus E)$$ and thus $$m^*(A \cup E) + m^*(A \cap E) =m^*(A) + m^*(E)$$

Is this a valid solution? I'm not sure if I can use $A$ the way I did here for Carathéodory's extension theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proof is fine. Notice however you are not using the Caratheodory extension theorem but [the Caratheodory Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion). Which in fact states that for $E$ to be $m^*$-measurable we must have that for every $A\subset X$ where $X$ can be any abstract space (and of course it is perfectly valid to take $X=\mathbb{R}^n$) then,

$$m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\backslash E)$$

Which is exactly the result you use.

In $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ we can use this criterion as a necessary and sufficient condition for $E$ to be Lebesgue measurable.